# Can I run setTimeout / setInterval inside $.submit()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am I doing this right?

```
var jForm= $("form:first");
jForm.submit(function( objEvent ) { setTimeout(somefunction(),500) });
```

The form is used to upload a file using an invisible iFrame. The above attempt has led me to an infinite loop for some reason...

I will really wish to know if I am able to call a function with setTimeout while manipulating submit with jQuery.

Note: I have previously raised [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491416/jquery-file-upload-to-remote-ftp-leads-to-infinite-loop), but I suppose I have included way too much information for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jForm.submit(function( objEvent ) { setTimeout("somefunction()",500) });
```

otherwise you will immediately call somefunction and execute the result in 500 milisecs

Comment: It would be even nicer if you did `setTimeout(somefunction, 500)` and avoided `eval` evilness.

Comment: or `jForm.submit(function( objEvent ) { setTimeout(function() { somestatements...;},500) });`

Answer (score 3):

Unless you prevent the default submit action of your form, it will be submitted by that default action before the function in `setTimeout` has time to run.

```
$('form:first').submit( function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout( someFunction, 500 ); // NOT setTimeout(somefunction(),500)
});
```

Also, don't call the function in `setTimeout()`. Pass a reference to the function (as above).

Bad:

```
setTimeout( 'myfunc()', 500 ); // bad, uses eval, runs in global scope
setTimeout( myfunc(), 500 ); // bad, runs function immediately, then passes
                             // returned value into setTimeout -- unless you
                             // are returning a function from myFunc
```

Good:

```
setTimeout( myfunc, 500 ); // function runs after 500 msec delay

setTimeout( function(){ // anonymous function, works fine
  do_this();
  do_that();
}, 500 ); 

setTimeout( function myfunc(){ // or name the function, easier for debugging
  do_this();
  do_that();
}, 500 );
```

Comment: after preventDefault(), how do you then allow the form to post as normal?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to return false at the end of the function to prevent the form submission, otherwise you're stuck with a race condition.

When the form is submitted, the page will start navigating somewhere else (the form's action). Unless you stop the form from submitting, somefunction() may not execute, or may not finish executing.

```
var jForm= $("form:first");
jForm.submit(function(objEvent) {
  setTimeout(somefunction, 500);
  return false; // Prevent form submission. Alternatively, you could call objEvent.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing up setTimeout and setInterval. setInterval *creates* a loop, so if you pass setInterval a funcion that itself calls setInterval, you're asking for trouble.